# Standard Layout Definitions

Tags: android

Is it possible to find out the contents / definitions of the built in Android Layouts.

If I use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` or `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` where can I find out the contents of those layouts so I know what views / ids are in them?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html#simple_list_item_1

The documentation at the above link tells me nothing about the contents of the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ANDROID_SDK/platforms/.../data/res/layout`, where `$ANDROID_SDK` is where you installed your SDK and `...` is a directory name based on an available API level for which you installed the associated SDK (e.g., `android-23`).

Comment: Wow that was fast :)